# Destination device disconnects while packet was in transit

Tags: network

What happens when the original destination IP address of a packet was reassigned to some other device(if the original device disconnects) while the packet was in transit?

Comment: That depends. Is the destination address on the same network, or is it on a different network, as the source device?

Comment: If it is in different network.

Comment: You are asking two different questions. If it was reassigned it could be routed to the new destination, if you just disconnect depending on the underlying layers it may end up being broadcasted to every output port on a switch or things like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As they say, timing is everything.  Because a packet can travel around the world in just a few tens of milliseconds, what happens depends on exact timing.

Assuming the new device is on the same network, the last hop router will forward the packet according to its ARP table. If the router has not been able to update its ARP table with the new host MAC address in time, it will forward the packet to a non existent MAC address, and no one will respond.  If there is a switch, it will either forward the packet to the old port, or it will flood the packet on all ports.  In either case, no one will respond to the packet.

If the router and switch have had enough time to update their tables, the packet will be delivered to the new host.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, the destination device is on a different network, so the packet may get delivered to the (new) device with the destination IP address.

There are some situations involving layer-2 addressing where the packet may get framed with a non-existent layer-2 address, and depending on the destination network. the frame may get delivered to a wrong device or dropped because the device with the layer-2 address doesn't exist.